# The odd number of partitions for reading data in Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working with 3GB data and I have read data using Spark RDD:

> rdd = sc.textFile("data.json")

When I used `rdd.getNumPartitions()`, the number of partition is 99! It is really odd.
If I even use `sc.textFile("data.json", 20)`, there are again 99 portions! Also, I cannot change the number of partitions by `rdd.repartition()` or `rdd.coalesce()`. It still keep 99 for the number of partitions.

I am really confused and I do not know why my data split into 99 partitions without any reasons! Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read how `textFile()` works [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#external-datasets). The part you are interested in is:

> The `textFile` method also takes an optional second argument for controlling the number of partitions of the file. By default, Spark creates one partition for each block of the file (blocks being 128MB by default in HDFS), but you can also ask for a higher number of partitions by passing a larger value. Note that **you cannot have fewer partitions than blocks**.

You can try to set the number of partitions but that number must be higher than the number of blocks stored for that file in the underlying HDFS. In your case there is still something that does not add up because 3*1024 MB should be split into 24 blocks -> 24 partitions and not 99 as `getNumPartitions()` indicates.

---

Just to give you the entire picture, HDFS is designed (and therefore optimized) to store very large files, that are split into chunks of 64/128MB. These chunks are distributed in different Datanodes based on the replication strategy to increase read performances and ensure high availability.